# Is there a command for formatting HTML in the Atom editor?

Tags: html, atom-editor, code-formatting

I would like to format my HTML with a command, as I do in Visual Studio, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  Is this possible in [Atom](https://atom.io/)? If not, are there other options?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Atom does not have a built-in command for formatting html. However, you can install the [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) package to get this behavior.

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac).
2. Type *Install Packages* to bring up the package manager.
3. Type *beautify* into the search box.
4. Choose [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) or one of the other packages and click *Install*.
5. Now you can use the default keybinding for atom-beautify <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to beautify your HTML (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on a Mac).

Comment: It is a contrary opinion that it is cool that Atom has the smallest core possible, so that you can install only what is necessary. ie, Atom can be used for developing non-web apps, which don't require those formatters...

Comment: There could be some custom installations like "Atom for Web developers" that come with the most downloaded packages related to the topic.

Comment: [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify), for example, has 685,927 downloads as of now... 9 in the last 10min, including mine!

Comment: atom-beautify is full of bugs. It doesn't work on real-word documents. It incorrectly adds newlines in headings if inline elements are presents. Switching from the JS Beautify engine to the Pretty Diff engine makes things worse --- inline elements such as `<dfn>` are wrapped inside of paragraphs.

Comment: I highly dislike the fact that `atom-beautify` doesn’t make use of personal indentation settings, and/or `.editorconfig` settings. It just formats everything **its** way.

Comment: Just FYI, in Atom for OS X the shortcut is COMMAND + SHIFT + P

Comment: @Diti `atom-beautify` is very customizable and does support `.editorconfig` settings. See https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/tree/master/examples/editorconfig-options for example.

Comment: From the cmd line you can run `apm install atom-beautify`

Comment: @GarretWilson Beautify is open source and permissively licensed, and you sound smart enough to fix those issues.

Comment: Yes, but my time is extremely limited. I have however put up $200 of my own money as a bounty on one of the worst bugs (which actually stems from js-beautify, the HTML formatting engine used by atom-beautify), and I even described how to fix it. There have been no takers so far. https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1033

Comment: atom-beautify is just too complicated for some simple beautifying and indenting. Why do I need PHP installed to simply beautify .php files?!

Comment: Note that to *beautify* Python, you will need to install **autopep8**: `pip install --upgrade autopep8`

Answer (score 14):

There are a few packages for prettifying HTML. You can find them by searching the Atom package archive:

1. Navigate to [the Atom site](https://atom.io)
2. Click the Packages link
3. Enter "prettify" in the search box

Or just go to this link: https://atom.io/packages/search?q=prettify

Once you've selected a package that does what you want you can install it by using the command: `apm install [package name]` from the command line or install it using the interface in Preferences.

When the package is installed, follow its instructions for how to activate its capabilities.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify

Includes many different languages, html too..

Answer (score 7):

You can add atom beauty package for formatting text in atom..

file --> setting --> Install

then you type **atom-beautify** in search area.

then click Package button..
 select atom beuty and install it.

next you can format your text using (Alt + ctrl + b)
or 
right click and select **beautify editor contents**

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Packages" in atom editor.
2. Then in "Packages" view choose "Settings View".
3. Choose "Install Packages/Themes".
4. Search for "Atom Beautify" and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Not Just HTML, Using `atom-beautify` - Package for Atom, you can format code for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, C, C++, C#, Objective-C, CoffeeScript, TypeScript, Coldfusion, SQL, and more) in Atom within a matter of seconds.

**To Install the `atom-beautify` package :**

- Open Atom Editor.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on mac), this will open the atom Command Palette.
- Search and click on `Install Packages & Themes`. A Install Package window comes up.
- Search for `Beautify` package, you will see a lot of beautify packages. Install any. I will recommend for `atom-beautify`.
- Now Restart atom and TADA! now you are ready for quick formatting.

**To Format text Using `atom-beautify` :**

- Go to the file you want to format.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on mac).
- Your file is formatted in seconds.