# Atom Beautify package shortcut / hot key in Atom editor not working

Tags: atom-editor

Atom says the shortcut for the Beautify command is `shift` + `option` + `B` 
 (`^⌥B`) on OS X. But that's not working. Instead, it inserts a `ı`. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a command for formatting html in the Atom.io editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189068/is-there-a-command-for-formatting-html-in-the-atom-io-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + Option + B</kbd> works for me.

<kbd>Shift + Option + B</kbd> also gives me the little `ı`, rather than beautifying.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Option + B works for me on OS X.
Ctrl + Alt + B works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Atom- Beautify is not working in my windows also.
From the suggestions, you can select any other packages too.
I selected "dli-atom-beautify" instead of "atom-beautify".
It worked for me. Hope it does for you too...